# Vercel CI/CD not trigger issue

Tags: devops, vercel, cicd

Why don't Vercel trigger build on git commit & push event? I got this issue, I linked my repo to Vercel, it is only deployed on linking time. because auto-trigger not happen, I tried to reconnect but it is only deployed again on the past commit, not latest commit.

Please do not copy/past GPT answer, I already tried. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this document https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/git
Vercel allows for automatic deployments on every branch push and merges onto the Production Branch of your GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket projects.

Check `git status` and `git branch -avv` to check:
-on which local branch you are
-what upstream branch is associated with your local branch

Answer (score 0):

Did you review your deploy settings?
I am curious what tech stack did you use for your project.

I think building your project in local environment is a good start to figure this out.
Vercel doesn't run the project in dev mode.
It builds the projects first then run it on production mode.
So, if you have some problems in building the project, you have to figure it out first.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: it works well in my local env.

Comment: Then, please review the vercel deploy settings like public directoy, build command etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure that the Vercel integration with your repository is still active. Sometimes, tokens or access permissions can expire or be revoked.
- Check if the webhook for Vercel is set up in your repository settings (on GitHub, GitLab, or Bitbucket). If it's not there or seems misconfigured, that could be the issue.
- Test the webhook to see if it's working correctly. Most git platforms like GitHub allow you to send a test payload to see if the service responds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the deploy log in more detail.
And also check the deploy configuration. As you know there is the options that which branch and which commit you are going to deploy.